# Deleting a single item from a QListview with QStringListModel as model

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QListview which i'm using to display book titles using a QStringListModel as model.  How can I delete the currently selected item?  I wanto to only be able to delete one book title which should be the currently selected title.  I read through a few similar questions but didn't find a clear answer anywhere.  I tried using a QModelIndexList declared in my deleteBookButtonClicked slot but keep getting a variable undeclared error...

Comment: you can delete it in the model and inform the view.  Easy way is to use reset model signals

Comment: I want to be able to find the currently selected string and then remove that from the QStringList.  I know how to remove it but how do I get the currently selected item in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// stringlistmodel.h

class StringListModel : public QStringListModel
{

public:

    explicit StringListModel(QObject* prnt=0);

    void deleteItem(const QModelIndex& index);
};

// srtringlistmodel.cpp
void StringListModel::deleteItem(const QModelIndex& index)
{
    if (!index.isValid() || index.row() >= stringList().size())
        return;
    removeRows(index.row(), 1);
}
```

use this like

```
StringListModel* model = new StringListModel(this);
model->setStringList(QStringList() << "Book 1" << "Book 2" << "Book 3");
ui->listView->setModel(model);
// C++11 style connect
connect(ui->pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [model, this]() {
    model->deleteItem(ui->listView->currentIndex());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the currently selected index in a view object called "myQViewObject", simply type:

```
myQViewObject -> currentIndex()
```